# More than one enum in namespace: the type or namespace "Gender" does not exist in namespace

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, enums

I have a Silverlight 5 project in Visual Studio 2012 and I have defined the following two Enums in the Web Project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace myProject.Web.MyEnums
{
    public enum AccountStatus
    {
        Active,
        Suspended,
        Inactive,
        Closed
    }

    public enum Gender
    {
        Male,
        Female
    }
}
```

I am now trying to use these Enums in one of my Views in the Silverlight project. In one of my methods I am trying to use these functions. The relevant section is as follows:

```
myObject.AccountStatus = myProject.Web.MyEnums.AccountStatus.Active;
myObject.Gender = myProject.Web.MyEnums.Gender.Male;
```

The first line works fine. The second line gives the error "The type or namespace name "Gender" does not exist in the namespace myProject.Web.MyEnums..." I have tried cleaning the project and rebuilding, but the error remains the same. It defies all logic as the "Status" and "Gender" enums are both declared - yet the one works and the other doesn't. I have also tried declaring the two enums in different files, but that also didn't work. This really seems weird - possibly a Visual Studio 2012 bug? Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Which project get compiled first? Are you using the up-to-date version of the web project reference in the silverlight project?

Comment: Well, I've actually tested it where I've commented out the two lines of code where I use the Enums so that both projects successfully and completely recompile. Then I uncomment the lines one by one. When I uncomment the first line, everything is fine. The moment I uncomment the second line, Visual Studio underlines it in red with the given error. So yes, it happens even when using the up-to-date version of the web project. One of the weirdest errors I've ever seen.

Comment: What happens if you end the enums with `};` instead of just `}`? Same problem?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. Same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have coincidentally stumbled upon why the one enum exists in the namespace while the other one does not.

It looks like the enums declared in the Web Project will not automatically be made available in the Silverlight project. Only if the enum is used somewhere in the Web Project will it actually be included in the namespace and thus be available in the Silverlight project. I'm not sure if this is as per design or is actually a bug in Silverlight.

I was using the "AccountStatus" enum as a variable somewhere inside my Web Project while I wasn't using the "Gender" enum. That is why the one was available and the other not.

What I did to solve the problem was simply to declare a variable of type "Gender" inside one of the functions in my DomainContext class even though I do nothing with it further than just declaring it (I don't think it HAS to be in the DomainContext class - I expect that it will work as long as you declare such a variable in any class in your Web Project.)

(For reference, the way I declared it was to define a function that simply expected the "Gender" as a variable):

```
public void DoNothingWithGender(Gender myGender) { /* Do nothing */ }
```

Once I declared this, the Gender enum was available in my Silverlight project. If I DON'T declare such a variable in the Web Project, the enum is not made available to the Silverlight project. Weird behavior, indeed, but this is what solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can verify that your code works fine on VS 2012. There are a number of other things you should verify.

- Make sure all relevant projects in your solution are set to build.
- Make sure that if a base project contains certain references such as System.Web.Extensions, the dependent projects must also contain the same references.

The second point above causes some really ambiguous errors not making it clear where the fault lies.